# Please tell whats the error... why it's not compiling?

Tags: c

the code below is giving segmentation code dump. Unable to get the output.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
     int main() 
    {   
      char word[]="CS311CS312CS313"; 
     printf("%s" , *word); 
     return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: `printf("%s" , *word);` --> `printf("%s" , word);` or `printf("%c" , *word);`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, it should have told you that the `printf()` line is wrong.

Comment: it said segmentation code dump..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  this

```
printf("%s" , word);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s" , *word);
```

Because the `*word` will be the value at `word[0]` which is a character. The `printf` however is looking for an array of chars, thus causing it to segfault. strings are just arrays of characters terminating with `'\0'`.

Comment: why aren't there any outputs using * as I was to test the pointer perspective